# When to use power ground with a desktop AC-DC power adaptor?

Tags: power-supply, grounding

I am designing a product that will use an AC-DC power adaptor like the one shown in the picture. Nearly all of these units have an IEC320 C14 3-conductor connector for the AC power cord. Some of them include the AC power ground in the DC output cable and some do not. Under what conditions do I need to connect the power ground to the chassis of my product? In case it matters, the design has a aluminum enclosure and it is intended to be used world-wide. The adaptor will probably produce +5V and +15V, about 50 W total.

[image: AC-DC power adaptor]

Answer (score 1):

Class II supplies, generally with a higher degree of isolation, do not require the third prong (but it may still be provided).

> A Class II or double insulated electrical appliance is one which has been designed in such a way that it does not require a safety connection to electrical earth (ground).

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes

Generally, it is up to designer to understand what this requires, for example, no standard will tell you which power supply architecture is better, or what circuit is required for good isolation.

For international sales it is also up to designer to harmonize and resolve the various national requirements.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I don't know what standards are applicable, but some of the power  adaptors I am looking at do say they are Class 1: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/260/GP50A_SPEC-1291937.pdf
It sounds like I should connect the power ground to the chassis if I use one of these.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not carry mains ground over to the DC side of an isolated converter, you often end up with a floating device. In any case you should still bond the chassis (or exposed metal) to either supply positive or negative, so ESD can flow to earth through the AC/DC converter.

Floating device has some advantage in that the potential of the device can be chosen by its surroundings (persons, machinery, other devices), e.g. you can stack output voltages etc. There is less of a problem with ground loops.

For measurement applications, it is often useful to have earth reference in your device though. That way, all devices agree easily on a common voltage reference and one avoids leaving the voltage range of some devices, as they float too far away from the other devices. I would argue, that it is also safer/easier to bond the chassis directly to earth potential. Allowing the chassis potential to be set by other potentially high powered devices could result in shock hazard and usually mandates an insulating cover over the metal chassis.